# How do I listen for a package to install before registering a ContentObserver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-broadcast

My issue here is more the result of the framework I'm using than Android itself. My app needs to register a ContentObserver after the user has installed a *specific* plugin associated with the AWARE framework. The framework has a sensor for installation of plugins, and sends a broadcast once this happens. Documentation can be found here: http://www.awareframework.com/installations/
I would like to accomplish this using a BroadcastReceiver.

I have a few questions regarding how to properly do this:

1. The way I interpret this documentation and Android is that if I register a BroadcastReceiver in my Manifest file with the intent filter "Installations.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME", every time a package is installed, it will activate my InstallationReceiver. If my understanding is still correct, I will be able to use getAction() on the received intent to parse the package name. Does this look like a correct understanding? Do intents works this way?
2. Is it proper to have my BrodcastReceiver in my Service class? Or should I make it a standalone class?
3. Did I register my receiver properly?

My MainService code:

```
package hcii.tracker;

public class MainService extends Service {


   public static final Uri ACTIVITY_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.aware.plugin.google.activity_recognition.provider/plugin_google_activity_recognition");
   public HashMap<Uri,ContentObserver> mContentObservers;

   public void onCreate(){

       Log.d("SERVICE", "Service created!");

       Context context = this;

       mContentObservers = new HashMap<Uri,ContentObserver>();
       //Activate installations sensor
       Aware.setSetting(context, Aware_Preferences.STATUS_INSTALLATIONS, true);
       //Activate Accelerometer
       Aware.setSetting(this, Aware_Preferences.STATUS_ACCELEROMETER, true);
       //Set sampling frequency
       Aware.setSetting(this, Aware_Preferences.FREQUENCY_ACCELEROMETER, 60);

       Aware.setSetting(getApplicationContext(), "frequency_google_fused_location", 60,
               "com.aware.plugin.google.fused_location");

       Aware.startPlugin(getApplicationContext(), "com.aware.plugin.google.fused_location");

       Aware.startPlugin(getApplicationContext(), "com.aware.plugin.google.activity_recognition");

       sendBroadcast(new Intent(Aware.ACTION_AWARE_REFRESH));
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {

        try {
            ContentObserver observer = mContentObservers.get(ACTIVITY_URI);
            getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);
            mContentObservers.remove(ACTIVITY_URI);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
            Log.d("SERVICE", "No ContentObservers registered");
        }
    }

    public class ActivityRecognitionObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.aware.plugin.google.activity_recognition.provider/plugin_google_activity_recognition");

        public ActivityRecognitionObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            // Get the latest recorded value

            Log.d("OBSERVER", "Change in activity data detected");
            Cursor activity = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                    "activity_name" + "DESC LIMIT 1");
            if( activity != null && activity.moveToFirst() ) {
                // Here we read the value
                String activity_name = activity.getString(activity.getColumnIndex("activity_name"));

                if (activity_name.equals("in_vehicle")){
                    Aware.setSetting(getApplicationContext(), "frequency_google_fused_location", 60,
                            "com.aware.plugin.google.activity_recognition");
                    Log.d("OBSERVER", "Recognized in vehicle");
                    Aware.startPlugin(getApplicationContext(), "com.aware.plugin.google.activity_recognition");
                }
                else {
                    Aware.setSetting(getApplicationContext(), "frequency_google_fused_location", 180,
                            "com.aware.plugin.google.activity_recognition");
                    Log.d("OBSERVER", "Recognized on foot");
                    Aware.startPlugin(getApplicationContext(), "com.aware.plugin.google.activity_recognition");
                }
            }
            if( activity != null && ! activity.isClosed() ) activity.close();

        }

    }

    public class InstallationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public InstallationReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action != null && action.equals("com.aware.plugin.google.activity_recognition")){

                ActivityRecognitionObserver so = new ActivityRecognitionObserver(new Handler());
                getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ACTIVITY_URI, true, so);
                mContentObservers.put(ACTIVITY_URI, so);
                Log.d("SERVICE", "Observer registered");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="hcii.tracker" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon, android:theme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name=".MainService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver android:name="hcii.tracker.MainService$InstallationReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Installations.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

1) You can use an inner class for your `BroadcastReceiver`, but if so it **must** be declared `static`, because Android needs to be able to instantiate the class itself using `new`. This is not possible in your current architecture (because the class is an inner class). In general it is better (easier) to use a stand-alone class for this.

2) Your Intent filter is wrong. The linked documentation from Aware indicates that the broadcast `Intent` is `Installations.ACTION_AWARE_APPLICATION_ADDED`, so your intent filter needs to look like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="Installations.ACTION_AWARE_APPLICATION_ADDED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

3) Once you have declared the `BroadcastReceiver` correctly, it will be triggered whenever Aware adds a plugin. The package name of the installed plugin is put into an "extra" in the `Intent`. To determine which plugin has been installed, you need to do something like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String packageName = intent.getStringExtra("Installations.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME");
    if (packageName != null && packageName.equals("your.plugin.package.name") {
        // Do your stuff here...
    }
}
```